# Python: Convert a CSV to string and add markers * between groupings of data

Tags: python, csv, split, reader

I have the following requirement and I was thinking Python would likely be a good candidate for performing the task.

I have a CSV file with Countries and all states in each country.  A sample of data is

```
Afghanistan,Balkh,My Val,CheckTHisout
Afghanistan,Bamyan,My Val2,CheckTHisout
Afghanistan,Badghis,My Val,CheckTHisout
Afghanistan,Badakhshan,Any Val,CheckT'Hisout
Afghanistan,Baghlan,My Val,CheckTHisout
Afghanistan,Daykundi,My Val,CheckTHisout
Albania,Berat,New Val,CheckT"Hisout"
Albania,Durrës,My Val,Check"THisout"
Albania,Elbasan,Any Val,CheckTHisout
Albania,Fier,My Val,CheckTHisout
Albania,Gjirokastër,My Val,CheckTHisout
Albania,Korçë,My Val,CheckT'Hisout
Albania,Kukës,My Val,CheckTHisout'
```

This is just a very small sample and even a subset of these 2 countries.

I'd like to convert my CSV file into one long continuous string (with no line breaks) and between each country add a "*" character.   Python is great for performing conversions however I haven't used it in a few years.  I tried to use the attached code just to check re: converting a full CSV to a string in a text file (even without marking country gaps with * and it falls over with the message

```
for num, val in reader:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

```
import csv

data = []
with open('CountryListingsAll4.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
    data.append(tuple(next(reader)))
    for num, val in reader:
        data.append((val))

print data
stringer = " ".join(str(x) for x in data)
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('' + stringer)
```

Does anyone know the best way this can be achieved? My CSV file is 3524 rows in length. I was surprised it fell over with the above error message.

(Note my data can have '', " and other characters within it.)

Any tips on this would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each line has four *fields* - `for num, val in reader` is trying to assign the four fields to two names - it doesn't know what you want. What do you want in `num`? what do you want in `val`?

Comment: Thank you @wwii you are correct. I have changed to use 4 values now val2,val2,val3,val4.

Comment: Do you know how I can determine the end of each country and effectively have one long string separated by "*" after each country section ends. For example

Comment: Afghanistan,Balkh,My Val,CheckTHisout,Afghanistan,Bamyan,My Val2,CheckTHisout,Afghanistan,Badghis,My Val,CheckTHisout,Afghanistan,Badakhshan,Any Val,CheckT'Hisout,Afghanistan,Baghlan,My Val,CheckTHisout,Afghanistan,Daykundi,My Val,CheckTHisout*Albania,Berat,New Val,CheckT"Hisout",Albania,Durrës,My Val,Check"THisout",Albania,Elbasan,Any Val,CheckTHisout,Albania,Fier,My Val,CheckTHisout

Comment: Where there is a * in CheckTHisout*Albania  when moving on the next country Albania?     Thanks for any help on this.